# Check if User exists in Wordpress Multisite

Tags: plugins, multisite, customization

Hi I am creating a custom Form to Register a new user in Backend. The problem is how I check if the user exists in another website of my Wordpress Network? And if not how can I register the new user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check existing user with "[username_exists](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/username_exists)" WordPress function and insert user using "[wp_insert_user](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user)" function as below for Network site also:

```
if( username_exists( 'username' ) ) {
    _e( 'Username already exists', 'your-text-domain' );
} else {
    _e( 'Username does not exists.', 'your-text-domain' );

    $userdata = array(
        'user_login'  =>  'username',
        'user_url'    =>  'http://example.com',
        'user_pass'   =>  wp_generate_password(),  
    );

    $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;

    //On success
    if( !is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
        _e( 'User created : ', 'your-text-domain' ); echo $user_id;
    }

}
```

For Wordpress Multisite We have to add this two functions **before** the code above:

```
$blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
$user_id = username_exists( sanitize_text_field( $_POST['user_name'] ) );

if ( $user_id && ! is_user_member_of_blog( $user_id, $blog_id ) ) {
    //Exist's but is not user of the current blog id
    $result = add_user_to_blog( $blog_id, $user_id, sanitize_text_field( $_POST['user_role'] ) );
}
```

Comment: +1, but you will need the email as well. Else it will pass the test and give you users that can't reset passwords, etc. as the default is an empty string `''` and [`email_exists()`](http://queryposts.com/function/email_exists/) will just return `false` and be done with it - which of course will leave you with the wrong impression that everything is ok.

Comment: Hi, I am testing your solution but it says that the user already exists. And it exists but is in another site of my wordpress network, how can I add an User that already exists in the network to the new wordpress site?

Comment: @Bernas : is new site out of the network site or added in the network site? In the Network site, username must be unique from all user of the Network.

Comment: @Bernas -- if the user already exists, you can add him/her to a given site using [`add_user_to_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_to_blog).